# How to use Data from one VBO to another

Tags: opengl

I want to create two circles at different Y positions.

Currently i am creating two separate VAO buffers for both of them.

```
// Create data for Top Cap
    dataCaps.push_back(0.0f);
    dataCaps.push_back(height / 2.0f); // only this value will change in the nextcircle
    dataCaps.push_back(0.0);
    // Normal
    dataCaps.push_back(0.0f);
    dataCaps.push_back(1.0f);
    dataCaps.push_back(0.0f);
    // Texture Coord
    dataCaps.push_back(0.5f);
    dataCaps.push_back(0.5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < iSegments + 1; i++)
    {
        float angle = 2.0f * M_PI * i / iSegments;
        // vertex data
        float x, y, z, tx, ty, tz;
        x = cos(angle)  * radius;
        y = sin(angle)  * radius;
        z = height / 2.0f;
        tx = cos(angle) + 0.5f;
        ty = sin(angle) + 0.5f;
        dataCaps.push_back(x);
        dataCaps.push_back(z );
        dataCaps.push_back(y);
        dataCaps.push_back(0.0f);
        dataCaps.push_back(1.0f);
        dataCaps.push_back(0.0f);
        dataCaps.push_back(tx);
        dataCaps.push_back(ty);
    }
```

I have very identical data with just few values changing in the next VBO of the VAO.

Can i use the existing data in the current VBO and change few values to create the next circle rather than creating a new data for the VBO of the next circle ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not say a lot about the setup of your rendering pipeline (are you using programmable shaders or the legacy fixed function pipeline?). In any case, you probably already apply some kind of model-view transformation to your vertices. It looks like you could easily incorporate your `height / 2.0f` shift there. In the legacy pipeline, you would add it to the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix (see [OpenGL Wiki: Viewing and Transformations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Viewing_and_Transformations) for an FAQ on the legacy transformations). In modern OpenGL you would pass the shift to the vertex shader by some means (e.g. as a uniform) and add it to the vertex coordinates there.

Comment: P.S. I overlooked the "glsl" - Tag. Sorry for that. So pass the shift to your vertex shader (if it will by many more than two circles, you could use a texture instead of a uniform). It might also be a nice example to start looking into instanced rendering (glDrawArraysInstanced and friends).